# Devise sign-up users on behalf of others (send sign-up email)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a devise User model, and I need a special behaviour.

Each user belongs to a company, and I want another company user to 'sign up' a new user.

My first thought was to use devise self: create a new RegistrationsController action

```
def new_company_user
  build_resource(company_id: params[:company_id])
  # ... 
end
```

then the view would point to the standard `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`

Then I ran into a problem: That Devise requires a new registration user to not be logged in.

So, there is probably another way.

If I create the user myself, how could I trigger Devise to send a sign-up email to the newly created user?

PS. I also considered the invitation strategy plugin, but decided not to use it, since I want both ways to work: 1. manual sign up, and the 'colleague' sign up. I may be missing something here?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do a custom action for this case where I'd send `company_id` and `email`, and assign a random generated password to the new user.

Next, after user is saved, I'd use `send_confirmation_instructions` method available in devise.

```
require 'securerandom'

def custom_action
  user = User.new(user_params)
  user.password = SecureRandom.hex #5b5cd0da3121fc53b4bc84d0c8af2e81
  if user.save
   user.send_confirmation_instructions
  else
   # redirect or..
  end
end
```

User will receive email to confirm his account.
Now, there are 2 ways here, either you'll sign him in directly after confirmation and you'll need somehow to make him change his current password either he will need to go through sign in form, that requires to send the generated password by confirmation mail to be used by user. Then he will have to change his password anyway. :)

> How to send the temporary password in email or make the user change
>   his password?

I'd add a Boolean field to user called let's say `generated_password` and set it by default false, and only when this account is created by other user I'd set it to true.
In confirmation email template I'd check if `generated_password` is true,than display additional info along with temp password.

Also this field could be used to make a before_filter in controllers to redirect user always to change_password path if `generated_password` is true, and set this to false when password was updated.

Comment: There is a typo near "Now, there are 2 ways here, either you'll  sing".It's "sign".

Comment: Thanks a lot @rmagnum2002. Your strategy works for me. Will accept this answer